# Memorylessness Property of exponential

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a exponential random variable with mean $\mu$. I know that from the memorylessness property we have $$Pr(X>s+t|X>s) = Pr(X>t)$$

Now, there's this question that I encountered "$X-d|X>D$ is exponential with mean $\mu$ by the property of memorylessness". Hence I tried to prove this(I just need to find pdf of $X-d|X>d$):

$f(x-d|x>d) = \dfrac{f((x-d) \cap (x>d))}{f(x>d)}$

and my dilemma is that I don't know $f((x-d) \cap (x>d))$, since $x-d$ is a point (when I plot in in a line segment). And their intersection is $\varnothing$ which I feel is wrong. Can you point out my mistake?

Comment: $ \dfrac{f((x-d) \cap (x>d))}{f(x>d)}$ does not make a lot of sense: $x-d$ is a number while $X \gt d$ is an event.  Presumably the numerator is really $f(x-d) I_{X\gt d}$ using an indicator function and the denominator is really $\mathbb P(X \gt d)$

Answer (score 1):

I think there's perhaps some typographical mistake here. What we want is that the distribution of $X - D \mid X > D$ is $E(\mu)$; call this random variable $Y$. To show this, we need to show that $P(Y > y) = e^{-y/\mu}$, ie
$$ P(X - D > y \mid X > D) = e^{-y / \mu}. $$
How do we do this? Let's take the conditional expectation with respect to $D$. I'll show the case where $D$ has a pdf, $g$ say, and I'll leave the general case to you. (It's basically the same, just you write $E(...)$ instead of $\int ... g(z) dz$.)
$$ P(X - D > y \mid X > D) = \int P(X - z > y \mid X > z) g(z) dz  = \int P(X > y) g(z) dz, $$
with the first equality by conditioning on $D = z$ and the second by the memoryless property. We now see that this integral is exactly $P(X > y) = e^{-y/\mu}$, since the two terms separate (and the integral of a pdf is 1).

For the general case, start off by writing
$$ P(X - D > y \mid X > D) = E[ P(X - D > y \mid X > D, D) ],$$
which uses the tower property, specifically that $P(Y > y) = E[P(Y > y \mid D)]$.